Identify this paranormal movie that may have been shown on the sci-fi channel
I watched this movie a very long time ago on TV but here is what I remember:

People move into a very strange old house.
A little girl knows something about it (or is one of the first to find a strange room through a key she found or maybe a dollhouse?).
There is some backstory to the house where the owner built a room to appear as if it's upside down.
The house has other strange rooms (a giant mirror room being important to the plot).
The original owners are now ghosts haunting the house.
and again, I'm pretty sure I saw this on the sci-fi TV channel somewhere between 2002 and 2005. 


While it wasn't shown on the sci fi channel (Unless as a rerun), I believe you are talking about the miniseries shown on ABC, "Rose Red". 
This is about a mansion with a paranormal past, being investigated by a modern team. It has a library with a mirrored floor, a room that was built to appear upside down, and there are several family members that disappear/die inside the house and haunt it.

I don't think Rose Red is the movie per the description. I've seen Rose Red twice (entire miniseries). I do not remember anything about a room which was upside down. I would think there would be other things more memorable in the movie than that. Anyway, I'll leave this as a comment and see what the OP thinks.

@Paulster2 - "Joyce and Steve point out that the home contains many optical illusions as well as an upside-down room and a library with a mirrored floor."
